# Using python and django to test for reference value

Tags: python, django, forms

I am someone who is both a doctor and researcher. I want to improve the work process of our department nurses by creating python code (which partly I already made in python) to help most beginning nurses.

The issue i can get my head around is trying to link my python code (input) to a webform like in django and for it to return the conditions i have set.

Ideally I want to end up for a webpage with a form asking multiple questions (multiple choice), which will return and action for the nurses to perform.

I am sorry if this is a very basis and easy question.

Comment: You might want to follow a complete tutorial first. A very thorough and well maintained tutorial apart from the official Django documentation is https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/